# Search Django Objects order_by(child_model_field)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have two models in my Django application.  The first one is `Journey` and Second is `Schedule`.
The `Schedule` models has a foreign key of `Journey` model. the schema of these models is as follow.

```
class Journey(models.Model):
    pass

class Schedule(models.Model):
    journey=models.ForeignKey(Journey)
    day=models.CharField(max_lenth=3, choices=days)
    start_time=models.TimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.day
```

What I want to do is that when I run query Journey.objects.all() it should return the journey in order_by(Schedule.start_time). Like Journey.objects.all().order_by(Schedule.journey)

is it possible in Django ORM or does this feature provided by django or i have to make a custom query to do it.

Guidance will be appreciable

Comment: what is ``Section``? You didn't mention it

Comment: It is Journey actually, I mistyped it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Journey.objects.all().order_by('schedule__journey')
```

The format for querying child model field/reverse lookup is like this:

```
ParentModel.objects.all().order_by('lowercase_child_modelname__fieldname)')
```

For details, check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: No It is not working. traceback is saying that `cannot resolve keyword schedule into fields list`. And i have to sort it by `schedule__start_time`

Comment: Plz check again if there is any misspelling and also verify if the `Schedule` model has FK relation with `Journey` as you have stated in your question. And you can just follow the format like I have mentioned in this answer for reverse lookup, for any field from child model.

Comment: I think the thing you are telling is about if `Journey` have a foreign key of `Schedule` model. This statement can be valid in reverse case like if we are fetching objects of `Schedule` model. i.e Schedule.objects.all().order_by(Journey__field_name)

Comment: I have a related name in field `journey=models.ForeignKey(Journey,related_name='scheduler')` when i tried using `Journey.objects.filter(scheduler__day='MO')` it give error `TypeError: Related Field got invalid lookup: day` but when i tried `Journey.objects.filter(schedule__day='MO')` it gives me field error.